# about a program "HelloWorld" of android application

Tags: android

Why can't I use `setContentView(R.layout.main)` in last line without `setContentView(tv)`? Please explain this to me.

```
package com.mue.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity 

{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setText("Hello, Android i am suvankar");

        setContentView(tv);
    }

}
```

Comment: not get ? you can set setContentView(R.layout.main) at last of function in this code............. what is issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the textview in the R.layout.main ( a xml file) this file contains the information of the objects in the activity. 
if you are using eclipse you can simple drag and drop a textview, just open the main file.
(folder res -> layout -> main.xml)

then yo have to call it in your program:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv); //<-- yo have to use the same ID that is in the main.xml file
```

and then you can set the text. all of this in the oncreate function.

```
tv.setText("Hello, Android i am suvankar");
```

Well, I hope I've helped. is my first response here

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call `setContentView()` twice in your `onCreate`. Either call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` or call `setContentView(tv)` but not both. I would prefer the first of the two... but you need to make sure the `TextView` is declared in your layouts XML.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first try to understand what `setContentView()` method does. Basically  `setContentView()` places your UI on your `Activity`. Now to create a UI component for your Activity, you can either use xml resource (e.g. R.layout.main) or you can obtain an instance of the UI component in your code and dynamically add it to your Activity. For example

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);

tv.setText("Hello, Android i am suvankar");

setContentView(tv);
```

In your case you created an instance of the `TextView` `tv`, set some text to it and added that to your Activity. Here you dont need to use `setContentView(R.layout.main)`. However if you have a xml layout (main.xml) in your layouts folder like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Hello World"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and at the bottom of your application you write `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, your should see a black screen with *Hello World* written on it. This is because here you created a `TextView` instance, set some text to it, but did not place it to your activity by calling 
`setContentView(tv)`, rather you added a completely different layout resource. If you use  `setContentView(tv)` and at the end of your `onCreate()` you add  `setContentView(R.layout.main)` then again you will see *Hello World* instead of "Hello, Android i am suvankar" because at the end you replaced your UI resource. However, if you forget to add your xml resource and call 'setContentView(R.layout.main)' compiler will issue an error for not finding the xml resource specified.